# What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for an exponential function over the positive integers to always produce an integer?

Tags: exponential-function, integer-sequences

Let $f(n)=ab^{P(n)}$ be an exponential function with domain $Z^+$, real base $b$, real coefficient $a$ and $P(n)$ an arbitrary polynomial function of $n$. Then what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the following to hold?

$f:Z^+\rightarrow Z$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sufficient conditions are easy to find, but characterising the above function is more difficult. There are non-integer rational values that $a,b$ can take that will still let $f$ exclusively produce integers, so restricting $a,b$ to the integers will not characterise $f$.

Comment: $ab^{P(n)} = b^{\log_b(a) P(n)}$ and $\log_b(a) P(n)$ is just another polynomial in $n$, so $a$ doesn't accomplish much here.

Comment: One challenge is crafting an answer based on $a$ and $b$.   For example, what happens if $a = 1$ and $b = \pi$?  Also, what happens if $a = \pi$ and $b = 1$? Also, what happens if $a = \pi$ and $\displaystyle b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$?